# FaceBook doesn't show OK button to proceed further

Tags: ios, facebook

I have implemented the latest version Facebook SDK 3.2 in my App. i have one problem, that if i have made a new FB account with no friends and no any additional info, then on login into Facebook account through my app, it doesn't show OK or Cancel button to proceed further. as shown in the screen shot below. 
If you have any idea about this plz Help!!![image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there seems to be a glitch in the FB UI changes. The changes has been reverted and the sharing is working fine :) :)